# Are there Psionic Rituals?

Tags: dnd-4e, psionics, rituals

Are there psionic-only rituals (don't see any in PHB3)? I see primal, arcane and divine rituals (though most seem to work with all three). The Psion has ritual caster so I'm wondering if there are specific psionic-only rituals out there.

If folks want to post some, that would be great too!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

*Psionic Power* also contains no rituals. The skill used for a ritual doesn't affect anything mechanically, so you can reflavor rituals as psionic without issue -- I do this for my psion. But yeah, it seems like a bit of a lack.

It's probably worth noting that rituals don't have an associated power source, just associated skills. WotC decided not to add a Psionics skill to parallel Arcana, Religion, or Nature, so I don't think we're likely to see anything specifically psionic. I think Arcana more or less fills in for a psionic skill, which may or may not be satisfying.

Mechanically speaking, it would be reasonable to house rule a Psionics skill that's an exact cognate to the Arcana skill. I'd use Psionics instead of Arcana for monster knowledge checks on aberrant creatures, and substitute it for appropriate rituals.

Answer (score 1):

Check out the Dark Sun Campaign Setting.  If there are any, they should be in there.  By reading a couple reviews, I found that there were 5 new rituals in the DSCS, but no word on if they were psionic or not.

The compendium has no psionic rituals, but should be updated with the Dark Sun material in October.

Comment: Dark Sun's rituals are primal-oriented. There's a section on altering existing rituals, but it doesn't mention psionics at all.

Comment: Too bad.  Seems like a missed opportunity.